# synchronized vs ReentrantLock vs AtomicInteger execution time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, mutex

I can see that `ReentrantLock` is around 50% faster than `synchronized` and `AtomicInteger` 100% faster. Why such difference with the execution time of these three synchronization methods: `synchronized` blocks, `ReentrantLock` and `AtomicInteger` (or whatever class from the `Atomic` package).

Are there any other popular and extended synchronizing methods aside than these ones?

Comment: How exactly did you get those performance numbers? Microbenchmarking in Java is very tricky because of the JIT and GC. You can easily get misleading results.

Comment: I think you mean the `java.util.concurrent` packages

Comment: I am just using `System.nanoTime()`, it is not an exhaustive test and the percentajes I gave were just indicative.

Comment: *Are there any other popular and extended synchronizing methods aside from these?* - yes - in Java 8 there's [StampedLock](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue215.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AtomicInteger` is much faster than the other two synchronization methods on your hardware because it is lock-free. On architectures where the CPU provides basic facilities for lock-free concurrency, `AtomicInteger`'s operations are performed entirely in hardware, with the critical usually taking a single CPU instruction. In contrast, `ReentrantLock` and `synchronized` use multiple instructions to perform their task, so you see some considerable overhead associated with them.

Comment: What does lock-free mean?

Comment: @dabadaba It means that operations on `AtomicInteger` will not block other threads for indefinite time intervals, allowing your threads as a group to always make some progress.

Comment: So more or less it means that it doesn't work along with the other threads, but in another level, in hardware level?

Comment: @dabadaba Well, locks also ultimately end up being processed in the hardware level. The difference is in how the two use hardware to achieve their results. Say, `AtomicInteger`'s `incrementAndGet` issues a CPU instruction to replace the old value with the incremented one, and get the old value back. Then it checks the old value against the value that it expected to see. Usually, this check succeeds right away. If it does not succeed, code loops back, and tries to do the same thing again until it succeeds. No waiting or giving back control is involved here - your thread thinks it's there alone.

Answer (score 9):

A number of factor effect this.

- the version of Java.  Java 5.0 was much faster for ReentrantLock, Java 7 not so much
- the level of contention.  synchronized works best (as does locking in general) with low contention rates.  ReentrantLock works better with higher contention rates.  YMWV
- how much optimisation can the JIT do.  The JIT optimise synchronized in ways ReentrantLOck is not.  If this is not possible you won't see the advantage.
- synchronized is GC free in it's actions. ReentrantLock can create garbage which can make it slower and trigger GCs depending on how it is used.

AtomicInteger uses the same primitives that locking uses but does a busy wait. CompareAndSet also called CompareAndSwap i.e. it is much simpler in what it does (and much more limited as well)

The ConcurrentXxxx, CopyOnWriteArrayXxxx collections are very popular.  These provide concurrency without needing to use lock directly (and in some cases no locks at all)

Comment: What do you mean with contention? Your answer complies that ReentrantLock is slower than synchronized, and I saw the opposite in my results, check my post again. Or maybe I am misunderstanding your response.

Comment: @dabadaba yes sometime ReentrantLock is faster and sometimes it is slower.  It all depends on factors like the ones I listed above. Even your CPU architecture can make a difference.  I have seen example where the same code with the same JVM run on different models of CPU (On a PC the other a laptop) got significantly different results as to which is faster.

Comment: @dabadaba contention means how many CPUs are attempting to use the same resource at the same time. Try your tests with just one thread per resource.

Comment: I was interested in the performance with multi-threading, not single-threading; but thanks, I will definetly check that out and see the results. But generally speaking and considering multi-threading (well, I mean, one thread per processor core => high contention rates?), would ReentrantLock be faster?

Comment: You missed the point completely. Think about how many lockable objects you have in your system.  Think about how many CPUs you have.  This means that generally speaking you have a few locks which are hot but most of them are very cold and even purely single threaded.

Comment: A low contention rate is less than one thread using a resource at any given moment. A medium contention rate would be one thread using the a resource on average contention rate but sometimes more. A high contention rate is when more than two thread try to use a resource on average which mean each thread is worse than half the speed it would be. Like I keep telling you there is multiple factors and no black/white answers.  You cannot say the results you get will be the same on another machine or another version of Java, or if the code was slightly different, or run for longer.

Comment: Oooh ok, I think I get what you're saying now, it sounds familiar to something I learned. So let's say my computer has 4 cores. If I create  1 thread, that'd be low contention rate, if I create 4 threads that'd be medium rate and if I create 10, 20, 100... that'd be high contention rate? Please say I am right.

Comment: @dabadaba if they are all using the same resource yes. If they are all using their own resources all the time. It will be low in every case.

Comment: @daba contention is a local not global concept. You have contended locks not systems. The only way to figure out how contended a lock is, is to profile the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are doing a common mistake evaluating those 3 elements for comparison.

Basically when a ReentrantLock is something that allows you more flexibility when your are synchronizing blocks compared with the synchronized key. Atomic is something that adopts a different approach based on CAS(Compare and Swap) to manage the updates in a concurrent context.

I suggest you to read in deep a bible of concurrency for the Java platform.

[Java Concurrency in Practice - Brian Göetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes & Doug Lea](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

There's a lot difference in having a deep knowledge on concurrency and know what a language can offer you to solve concurrency problems and taking advantage of multithreading.

In terms of performance, it depends on the current scenario.